# Can i add all indexing in single table if my tables are in many to many relationship?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, mysql

Example:-I have 3 tables product, branch & employee.Those are in Many to many relationship.So can i add all primary keys of those in new table as a foreign key for referencing?Instead of creating 3 different tables.means combination of product_branch, product_employee & branch_employee.

Answer (score 0):

that relationship may have meaning - or maybe not.

probably this does not avoid the need to have other normalized relationships between just the employee and the branch for example.

Comment: not too much without some concrete examples.  it seems you are trying to denormalize for some reason - and that generally is not the right approach.  ONLY if the resulting table with all those repeating id's has a unique meaning would it make sense to jam everything in one table.